# python behave bdd framework. how to execute remaining step when a step fails

Tags: python-3.x, cucumber, python-behave

I am using python BDD framework. where i need to continue with the rest of the step even after one step fails.

```
Scenario Outline: Components
        Given I load the website
        When I go to "Dashboard" page
        Then I see this component "<boxes>"
```

When the second step in the above scenario fails. I wish to continue with the next steps even the above step failed. How can i proceed

Answer (score 1):

You could, for example, add tag `@runner.continue_after_failed_step` to your scenario and add the following code to your environment.py:

```
from behave.model import Scenario

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
              if "@runner.continue_after_failed_step" in scenario.effective_tags:
                  scenario.continue_after_failed_step = True
```

Or if you want to continue the execution after a failed step for all scenarios, you could simply add this to your environment.py:

```
from behave.model import Scenario
      
def before_all(context):
              userdata = context.config.userdata
              continue_after_failed = userdata.getbool("runner.continue_after_failed_step", False)
              Scenario.continue_after_failed_step = continue_after_failed
```

and add these parameters to your behave.ini file on root directory:

```
[behave]
show_timings = false

[behave.userdata]
runner.continue_after_failed_step = true
```

If you need more information about it, you can find the implementation from behave project here [Behave Github](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/features/runner.continue_after_failed_step.feature)