# How to fail a step definition and continue to the next steps python behave

Tags: python, exception, python-behave

I am currently on Python Behave.

I have exactly 1 scenario in my feature file. This scenario contains 5 steps. At step 3 I would like to test a condition and if the condition fails I would like to mark that particular step as failed and move on to the next steps (steps 4 and 5 ).

How do I do this?

Currently I have an if-else block, and if the 'if' condition fails, the else block is run and raises an exception, which fails this particular step. But the execution stops here and does not proceed to the next steps (step 4 and step 5).

I am on Python 3.9, and Behave version 1.2.6

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62525445/python-behave-bdd-framework-how-to-execute-remaining-step-when-a-step-fails

Comment: This does not work. Creating those files (behave.ini and environment.py) seems to have no effect at all.  I was wondering if there was a programmatic solution to this. @DevangSanghani

Comment: No direct way it seems, but there is something here : https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/953

Comment: https://codoid.com/automation-testing/python-behave-bdd-framework-overview/